# ^Uri to GetAsync

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm new in UWP and c++ too.
I'm trying to write a simple app that handles http-api.
My example:

```
void ForecastFromMSW::MainPage::GetTheCity(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    String ^mystr = "http://google.com"; // creating a string object 
    Uri url(mystr); // crating an url object
    HttpClient cli; //creating an object of HttpClient
    cli.GetAsync(url); // pass url object to cli
}
```

a message from compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ForecastFromMSW, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MainPage.xaml.cpp
1>c:\users\9maf4you\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\forecastfrommsw\forecastfrommsw\mainpage.xaml.cpp(38): error C2664: 'Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationWithProgress<Windows::Web::Http::HttpResponseMessage ^,Windows::Web::Http::HttpProgress> ^Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient::GetAsync(Windows::Foundation::Uri ^,Windows::Web::Http::HttpCompletionOption)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Windows::Foundation::Uri' to 'Windows::Foundation::Uri ^'
1>  c:\users\9maf4you\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\forecastfrommsw\forecastfrommsw\mainpage.xaml.cpp(38): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>  c:\users\9maf4you\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\forecastfrommsw\forecastfrommsw\mainpage.xaml.cpp(38): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I see, that compiler can't convert one type to another and I understand I have to pass ^Uri to GetAsync. But I don't know what I should do.
Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

In C++/CX, objects are usually instantiated using [ref new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8.aspx), returning a ref-counted object handle. The easiest way to fix your code would be to replace

```
Uri url(mystr);
```

with

```
Uri^ url = ref new Uri(mystr);
```

The compiler will generate code to decrement the ref-count on `url` when it goes out of scope. The object is automatically destroyed, when the reference count reaches zero.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler told you the problem

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'Windows::Foundation::Uri' to 'Windows::Foundation::Uri ^'

The fix is to use the managed "address of" operator which is `%`, `cli.GetAsync(%url);`.  You can see this same problem with a very simple test program:

```
ref class Foo sealed {};
void f(Foo^) {}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Foo foo;
    f(%foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that since you're calling a `*Async()` method, you probably want to seriously consider using C#.

Comment: The question is about C++/CX, not C++/CLI. Your answer does not apply.